# Fresh ESXi 6.7u2 install not accessible on management IP

Tags: networking, hypervisor

After building the server, I connected my laptop to Ethernet port marked as 1 and attempted to ping the IP.  This failed.  I tried the other 3 ports, same result.  Server has 4 NICS so I connected them all to a gig switch along with my laptop, but still could not access the management IP.

Big G search engine wasn't my friend this time - I didn't find anything that helped.

The server is a Lenovo ST550.  There are 2 LOM ports, a management port and a dual port NIC paddle board.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I took to isolate and resolve.

I enabled the ESXi shell at the console (under troubleshooting).

I entered the console (ALT+F1) and Logged in.

```
[root@localhost:~] esxcli network nic list
```

I see 5 NICs, 4 Ethernet ports and one vusb0.  The vusb0 is the embedded IBM XClarity Controller/IMM/BMC device.

```
[root@localhost:~] esxcli network ip interface ipv4 get
```

Shows me that vmk0 has the IP I set.

```
[root@localhost:~] esxi network switch standard list
```

Shows the vSwitch only has the vusb0 NIC.  Bingo, there's the problem.

```
[root@localhost:~] esxcli network vswitch standard uplink add -u vmnic0 -v vSwitch0
```

I add a LOM NIC to the vswitch in the event there is a driver or port issue.

```
[root@localhost:~] esxi network switch standard list
```

lists vSwitch0 with uplinks as vusb0,  vmnic0

I still cannot ping the IP.

```
[root@localhost:~] esxcli network vswitch standard uplink add -u vmnic2 -v vSwitch0
```

I add a second port to use the paddle board NIC.

```
[root@localhost:~] esxi network switch standard list
```

lists vSwitch0 with uplinks as vusb0, vmnic2, vmnic0.

I still cannot ping the IP.

```
[root@localhost:~] esxcli network vswitch standard policy failover get -v vSwitch0
```

I see vusb0 is listed as the active adapter and vmnic0 & vmnic2 are listed as standby.

```
[root@localhost:~] esxcli network vswitch standard uplink remove -u vusb0 -v vSwitch0
```

I remove the vusb0 NIC.

```
[root@localhost:~] esxcli network vswitch standard policy failover get -v vSwitch0
```

Now the Active Adapter is listed as vmnic0.  After a few seconds, I can ping the interface and access the web UI.

If I did have a question, it would be, Why?  Why the USB port used by the BMC?